# Как перенаправить сайт на его алиас, если основной сайт офлайн?

Tags: nginx, redirect

Стоит задача, если основной сайт оффлайн, допустим: mydomain.com - он недоступен, но он имеет алиас, mydomain.today, как мне при помощи nginx, сделать так, если основной сайт оффлайн, то чтобы все запросы вели на этот алиас, включая те страницы где ссылки прописаны основного домена. Есть возможность решить эту проблему?

Comment: Хм. Чем вы собираетесь перенаправлять если вы оффлайн?

Comment: Кажется тут логичнее смотреть в сторону cloudflare или аналогов.

Comment: а если сайт недоступен. потому что nginx упал? рекомендую смотреть в сторону ha-proxy.